# Are sets in ZFC a primitive notion?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, set-theory, foundations

I read everywhere (including here on math.stackexchange) that the notion of set in ZFC is primitive. To my (probably mis-)understanding, though, a primitive notion is a concept that is not defined in terms of previously-defined concepts.

This is where my confusion begins. Aren't ZFC axioms there exactly to define what a set is (in first-order logic terms)? Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't something a set exactly if and only if satisfies those axioms? With those at hand, one can for example show that {1,2} is a set but the collection of all sets is not a set.

To my very uneducated brain, this is what you do with any other definition in math: you say that something is something if and only if it satisfies certain axioms.

Therefore I am wondering: how does a set differ from say, a measure of probability? For both of them, I have a bunch of axioms that formally define what they are.

I do see that $\in$ and $=$ are primitive notions because they are indeed never defined but simply appear in the ZFC axioms. However, sets do. What am I grossly misunderstanding?

Comment: The ZFC axioms specify how sets *behave*. They do not tell us what sets *are*.

Comment: But what's preventing me to say that something is a set if and only it behaves like a set?

Comment: If a set with a binary relation satisfies ZFC, then it's a *model* of ZFC, and its *elements* are the 'sets' *in that model*.

Comment: ZFC does not include a formal definition of the form: $X$ is a set iff ______________. It seems such a definition is simply not required.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the narrative that sets are a primitive notion in ZFC is slightly incorrect. A more precise statement is that ZFC never discusses a notion of “set” at all. Instead, what is discussed is “set membership”; *that* is the primitive notion. Saying that ZFC defines “what a set is” or “how a set behaves” is, in my view, not correct.

At best, ZFC describes how the collection of all sets behaves.

An analogy would be the axioms of a group. These axioms define how the group itself behaves. They do not talk about the nature of group elements; they only discuss how group elements are related to each other by the group operation.

Similarly, ZFC describes how a universe of sets should behave. It does not discuss the nature of individual sets; it only discusses how sets are related to each other by the set membership predicate.

Comment: Thank you for attending me on this, Mark. Could you tell me what a "primitive notion" *is* (or ironically how it is defined:-)) in your view. After all the question (is set a primitive notion?) can only be discussed if this is clear for every participant of the discussion. For me it is a concept that is undefined. You could compare it with an element that has no predecessors wrt a well-founded relation. In what sense does this differ from your conception of primitive notion?