# Formal Definition of a set membership

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

How do we define x $\in$ Y? What does it mean precisely/formally? Or is it so basic that it is undefinable and you gotta get it or you are lost? Could one define x $\in$ Y $\iff$ $\mathcal I \vDash$ Y(x) or would it be circular since Y(x) is basically defined as x $\in$ Y? Could one define x $\in$ Y $\iff$ x $\land$ (x $\to$ Y) (that is probably how a computer would check it)?

Comment: In classical set-theory there are two primitive (i.e. undefined) concepts: set and the relation $\in$. Statements like $x\in Y\iff P(x)$ can be used to define the set $Y$. This because $Y$ is *determined* by its elements (i.e. the sets $x$ that satisfy $x\in Y$) according to the [axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#1._Axiom_of_extensionality).

Comment: The axioms of your preferred set theory define it. Alternatively, you can approach it from an "informal" point of view: $x \in A$ iff $A$ is a collection of mathematical objects, e.g. natural numbers, functions, and $x$ is an individual that belongs to that collection: a single number, function.

Comment: There is no formal definition of a set in any widely used set theory. If there was one, it would be rarely if ever be used in proofs. For the most part, mathematicians don't concern themselves with determining whether or not something is a set. Informal dictionary definitions seem to be sufficient as a starting point for discussions.

Comment: So is the notion of „is element of“ not definable or not defined (out of disinterest, but it could if needed)? I mean could one not just look at how a computer/Turing machine validates if an element is in a set and formally write down what the computer does to define $\in$? I know we cannot define anything for there will be always fundamental notions we have to understand naturally, but $\in$ seems not such a fundamental notion at first glance.

Comment: @Mauro: How do the ZFC axioms define the $\in$ relation? In my opinion they presuppose it.

Comment: It does not define it in a "strict" way: it is not possible to define everything. It defines how to "use" it: through axioms.

Comment: @drhab “set” is not a primitive notion in ZFC-style set theory. For a more complete explanation, see this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4476729/798694